# Unable to build and run imported project with Connection refused and Gradle errors

Tags: java, spring, rest, gradle, intellij-idea

I was trying to clone this repository from github:
https://github.com/ziakhalid/spring-rest-sample.git

which i then imported project from external model (gradle) and using this project configurations
[image]

the building result was a connection refused error message together with sync failed and error in run build and configure build
[image]

when i probe in the error of run build this was the list of gradle error message
[image]

and the same goes to configure build, the error list here
[image]

**i have tried refreshing my gradle without any result and adding gradle under the gradle tab
[image]

which feedbacks to me that the project is already registered.**

Comment: 0
down vote

Looks like some connection error. Do you use any antivirus software or firewall/proxy?

Comment: It would be good to paste error text here